# How to display images that overlay video feed?

Tags: linux, video, camera, raspberry-pi, video-processing

I want to make a On-Screen Display for my drone similar to [this](http://diydrones.com/video/exrtemeosd-w-apm-support-added)
 one.

I plan to use a Raspberry Pi and Camera Board.  Then I want to display information like heading and battery voltage on top of the streaming video feed.  I hope to just let the video stream and at the same-time display a transparent image on top of it.  This way I don't have to manually manipulate the video feed and consequently introduce a delay in the video feed.

My question is what is a good method for overlaying this information in real-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/). (Hover your mouse over this link for more information.) The only requirement you would have would be you would need to connect a USB webcam instead of the camera to the CSI for this to work.